# Linux bash script: How can I detect an error on a RESTORE DATABASE query on msssql-server?

Tags: sql-server, linux, bash

Syncing a windows app with a linux website,  I use a bash script which transfers each day a MS-SQL database from a Windows machine to a Linux installation, and uploads it to the mssql-server with the code below:

```
sqlcmd -b -S localhost -U SA -P <password> -Q "RESTORE DATABASE <dbname> FROM DISK = '/home/<user>/$newdb' WITH MOVE '<x_Data>' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/<dbname>.mdf', MOVE 'x_Log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/<dbname>_Log.ldf'"
```

Most of the times this line works perfectly. But there are instances in which restoration fails with an error like the following:
"Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired."

I can't seem to find a way to detect these errors and make the script respond accordingly by repeating the process or restarting the mssql-server.

Does anyone knows how to detect the failed query response?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're already using the `-b` flag to  [terminate the job if it fails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility). This sets the **exit status** of that command to non-zero. (A bit like how `%ERRORLEVEL%` works on Windows.)

The [last command's exit status](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) can be accessed in a bash script with `$?`.

Something like this could work:

```sh
sqlcmd -b ...
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "SQL upload failed"
  mail -s "sql error!" "admin@example.com" "sql broke again"
  exit 1
fi
```

It can of course be shortened. Even something like `(sqlcmd -b ...) || (echo "Failed"; exit 1)` might work for you.

Comment: Alternatively, have bash exit on failure with [`set -e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html). This avoids creating logic for each execution of `sqlcmd -b`.